# jQuery selector $(this) not working as expected

Tags: jquery

When submitting an ajax request, I would like to toggle a class before send, toggle it back on error, or keep it if everything turns out ok. But the `$(this)` selector does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why. I'm using jQuery 1.4.3.

*html*

```
<a class="vote-down vote-down-112 state-3" data-postid="112" data-voteid="6">down</a>
```

*js*

```
$('.vote-down').click(function() {
    var voteData = '&postId=' + $(this).data('postId') + '&voteId=' + $(this).data('voteid');
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'script',
        url: "myURL" + "?format=js" + voteData,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { $(this).toggleClass("status-3"); },
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) { $(this).toggleClass("status-3"); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: FYI You may want to upgrade to `1.4.4` as there are a number of bugs you can avoid in doing so (not related to the issue here).

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I'll do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` by default refers to the `ajax` object itself, if you want `this` to be something specific, use the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to set what `this` is in your callbacks, like this:

```
$('.vote-down').click(function() {
  var voteData = '&postId=' + $(this).data('postId') + 
                 '&voteId=' + $(this).data('voteid');
  $.ajax({
     context: this,
     dataType: 'script',
     url: "myURL" + "?format=js" + voteData,
     error: function() { $(this).toggleClass("status-3"); },
     beforeSend: function() { $(this).toggleClass("status-3"); }
  });
  return false;
});
```

I removed the function arguments just to clean up, they're not needed if you're not using them.

Comment: +1 I think the `context` property may be one of those little known features.

Answer (score 2):

Common mistake. `this` refers to the XHR request, not to the element:

```
$('.vote-down').click(function() {
  var that = this; // save a reference to the element;

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'script',
    url: "myURL" + "?format=js" + voteData,
    error: function() {
      $(that).toggleClass("status-3");
    },
    beforeSend: function() { 
      $(that).toggleClass("status-3");
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

That is because jQuery calls you error and beforeSend function like this: `userfunction.apply( xhr[, args] );`, which makes the `this` keyword refer to the XHR.

Comment: There's a property for this in the options ;) And just for accuracy, that's not how they're called, for example `beforeSend` is called using `call` and that argument: `s.beforeSend.call(s.context, xhr, s)` (`s.context` *defaults* to the settings object itself if not set).